# Visual Studio 2019 - define a pragma or macro in launch.vs.json

Tags: visual-studio, predefined-macro

I need to define a precompiler element(pragma? macro? not sure how you call them) as DEBUG in a cmake project loaded with VS

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [        
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "main.exe (bin\\main.exe)",
      "name": "main.exe (bin\\main.exe)",
      "pragmas": [
        "DEBUG":"true"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so it can be used in the code as

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#if DEBUG
```

is it possible ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`launch.vs.json` contains all the settings to help Visual Studio understand how to **launch** your **already compiled** executable.

What you're looking for is a place that gives the **compiler** (not the launcher) the instructions how to create the executable (depending upon the preprocessor directives).

Different ways of doing this, depending on your project type.

- If it's a native VS project (`.sln` solution, just for clearance): right click on your Project, click on `Properties`, then move to `C/C++ / Preprocessor` and fill in `Preprocessor definitions` field.
- If you're writing a CMake project, you can use the command [`add_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions) in your `CMakeLists.txt` list file.